# Slow SQL Queries over local net

Tags: sql-server, sql, query, slow-connection

Slow Queries for SQL over 1Gb link between servers using just SSMS

Server Configs:

```
Main SQL Node:
32GB Ram
16 cores
Sage Evolution Server:
16 cores
16GB ram
```

The config of the servers is that they both on an ESXi host with a 1Gb interlink between them that i have assigned the IPs of 10.0.0.0/24

```
Results query to do 900k results takes:
23 Seconds on the main server
58 Seconds on the Sage server

So far the bottleneck seems to be the Interlink between the servers:
10GB file Copy Speed: 1Gb/s
SQL Queries 30Mb/s
```

Any more info needed will gladly provide it

Answer (score 0):

I'm a SQL guy, so I would start suspecting the SQL Server.
May I suggest that you download and run sp_Blitz from www.brentozar.com?
Just to see if you have a setting that is not correct.

I've also found that SSMS is not able to receive and show many rows as fast as the SQL Server is able to provide the data. Try disable the result set in Query -> Query Options -> Results, click "Discard results after execution".